# countif/conditional vba/locking macro

Tags: vba, excel

`sub financials`

```
dim g as long
dim r as long
dim y as long
dim oh as range
dim vr as range
dim sum as long
set vr = Sheets("Financials").Range("B5:B53")
set oh = sheets("Financials").Range("B2")

y = application.worksheetfunction.countif(vr, "y")
g = application.worksheetfunction.countif(vr, "g")
r = application.worksheetfunction.countif(vr, "r")

if g = 5 then
oh = "G"
elseif g = 4 and y = 1 then
oh = "G"
elseif r>=2 then
oh = "R"
elseif y >= 1 and r>= 1 then
oh = "R"
elseif y >=3  then
oh = "R"
elseif g=3 and y=2 then
oh = "Y"
elseif g=4 and r=1 then
oh = "Y"
elseif g=2 and y=3 then
oh = "Y"
elseif y=2 then
oh = "Y"
end if
end sub
```

this is what i have written so far and it works fine but as you can see there are 5 cells taht determine the overall cell. But i've realized sometimes there's less than 5 cells - sometimes there's only 2 or 3. If there are less than 5 this formula is not applicable since it needs 5 cells to determine the overall cel.

I was thinking of using sum function. so summing up the countifs of y, g, r and if that sum is equal to 1,2,3 then it would do the following command but i'm not sure how to do that

if sum of y,g,r = 3 then do the following:

```
if g = 3 then
oh = "G"
elseif g = 1 and y = 2 then
oh =  "Y"
elseif g = 2 and r = 1 then
oh = "Y"
elseif g =1 and y = 1 and r =1 then
oh = "R"
elseif y = 2 and r = 1 then
oh = "R"
elseif r = 3 then
oh = "R"
```

if sum of y,g,r = 2 then do the following:

```
if g = 2 then
oh ="G"
elseif g = 1 and y = 1 then 
oh = "y"
elseif y = 1 and r =1 then
oh = "R"
```

and etc

also i need to lock the worksheet but the macro has to keep running. how do i do that?

Comment: what issue are you getting right now when there are less than 5? Also what do you mean by "5 cells"?

Comment: [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014785/ratio-conditional-requirements-for-vba-excel)  is a link to the question where he created this rule from 5 cells to determine the value of another.  It may be time to switch to a case statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a select case after getting the sum of the cells.  For this example I would use select case because it is a little neater to me than using ifs and else ifs, but that is personal preference.  For more examples of select case check [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141691)

Locking the worksheet requires one line:

```
sheets("worksheetname").protect userinterfaceonly:=True
```

for more on worksheet locking check out this [link](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Protection.aspx)

```
Sub financials()

Dim g As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim oh As Range
Dim vr As Range
Dim sum As Long
Dim i
Set vr = Sheets("Financials").Range("B5:B53")
Set oh = Sheets("Financials").Range("B2")

y = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(vr, "y")
g = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(vr, "g")
r = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(vr, "r")

x = y + g + r

Select Case x
    Case Is = 5
        If g = 5 Then
        oh = "G"
        ElseIf g = 4 And y = 1 Then
        oh = "G"
        ElseIf r >= 2 Then
        oh = "R"
        ElseIf y >= 1 And r >= 1 Then
        oh = "R"
        ElseIf y >= 3 Then
        oh = "R"
        ElseIf g = 3 And y = 2 Then
        oh = "Y"
        ElseIf g = 4 And r = 1 Then
        oh = "Y"
        ElseIf g = 2 And y = 3 Then
        oh = "Y"
        ElseIf y = 2 Then
        oh = "Y"
        End If

    Case Is = 3
        If g = 3 Then
        oh = "G"
        ElseIf g = 1 And y = 2 Then
        oh = "Y"
        ElseIf g = 2 And r = 1 Then
        oh = "Y"
        ElseIf g = 1 And y = 1 And r = 1 Then
        oh = "R"
        ElseIf y = 2 And r = 1 Then
        oh = "R"
        ElseIf r = 3 Then
        oh = "R"
        End If

    Case Is = 2
        If g = 2 Then
        oh = "G"
        ElseIf g = 1 And y = 1 Then
        oh = "y"
        ElseIf y = 1 And r = 1 Then
        oh = "R"
        End If

    'more cases here

    End Select


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way for somone to be not able to access the VBA codes? like competely hide the VBA codes unless I unprotect the worksheet?

Comment: hit ctrl-r (to see the project explorer)
with your project selected in the project explorer
Tools VBAProject Properties
Protection tab.  Keep in mind that excel isn't exactly the most secure system.  There are commercial products that will be able to gain access to these passwords or just disable them

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as the answer if this is what you were looking for